# Dojo Datagrid - Style selected row programmatically

Tags: datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

Is it possible to style the selected row of a Datagrid programmatically?

Can anyone give a snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/rjRAA/2/) with modified reference guide example):

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    id: 'grid',
    store: store,
    structure: layout,
    rowSelector: '20px',
    onClick: function() {
        // ( selection.selected is array for multiple)
        var index = this.selection.selectedIndex,
        // typically 1 here, mess with it if nogo on solution
        viewindex = 1,
        RAWROWNODE = this.views.views[viewindex].rowNodes[index]

    }
}, document.createElement('div'));
```

You can also look into the stylesheet, used by grid component.

```
.dojoxGridRow,
.dojoxGridRowOdd,
.dojoxGridRowSelected {
}
```

Comment: Indeed the solution was to override the css the grid was using. To be more specific I use the claro theme and the claroGrid.css and I inside that I changed it: 
For the Selected Row:
.claro .dojoxGridRowSelected .dojoxGridRowTable tr td[style] {
 background-color:#cee6fa !important;
}
For the Over Row:
.claro .dojoxGridRowOver .dojoxGridCell {
 background:url("images/row_back.png") #ABD6FF repeat-x !important;
 border-top:1px solid #769DC0;
 border-bottom:1px solid #769DC0;
}

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply overriding the right css class?
Otherwise you might want to look at onStyleRow and styleRowState function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 dojo.connect(grid, 'onStyleRow', this, function (row) {
    if (grid.selection.selectedIndex == row.index) {
       row.customStyles += "color: red;";            
    }

    grid.focus.styleRow(row);
    grid.edit.styleRow(row);
});
```